# Who is the Registered Owner of the Following Patents and is Their Assignee Recorded?

Tags: assignment

What person or group is the registered owner or registered assignee of the following design patents
8257475
9182080
9574710
10100980

Comment: They are not design patents; they are US utility patents. To get the answer yourself go to https://assignment.uspto.gov/patent/index.html#/patent/search/resultAbstract?id=8257475&type=patNum and put in the patent numbers - one at a time.

Comment: You should use normal capitalization rather than ALL CAPS to be taken more seriously in future questions.

Comment: I edited you title to remove the all caps. All caps is the equivalent of yelling on the internet and is considered extremely rude.

Answer (score 1):

I'm formalizing George White's comment as an answer since it is so useful. As George White points out, those are US utility patents, not design patents. Go to the [USPTO Patent Assignment Search page](https://assignment.uspto.gov/patent/index.html#/patent/search/resultAbstract?id=8257475&type=patNum), select "Look up by Patent Number" and type in the patent number (digits only). It's really easy. Looking at the first number you get the following result. You can scroll down to see the entire entry.

[image]

Comment: thanks again @EricS

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I kind of felt like I was stealing your answer.

Comment: I was put off enough by the question overall that I was not inspired to post an answer  - and I don't need the rep points. Thanks for being more helpful than I was motivated to be.